# Use Raspberry Pi (and C#) in a bicycles

Tags: bike-computer, technology, design

Any full source code sample projects about Raspberry Pi (or another) using it in bicycles ?

Maybe interesting for create a dashboard in bike for manage lighting ?

Examples:

- [live web bicycle (gps logging and web dashboard)](http://jeremyblythe.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/live-web-bicycle-dashboard-using.html)
- [RaspberryPi.Net](https://github.com/cypherkey/RaspberryPi.Net/) (not relevant)

Comment: Nah, you should be using Objective-C.

Comment: Nah, Python. Do you even Linux, bro?

Comment: Raspberry Pi for bicycles in any language can I develop using PC Windows 7 ?

Comment: You can develop Python using any text editor. There are extensions which add Python support to MS Visual Studio.

Comment: wow - all these cyclists cutting loose with their real passion!

Comment: http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/raspberry-pi-dynamic-headlight-detects-and-projects-your-bikes-speed/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming.

Comment: Most likely project would be Android based. Even the cheapest driod comes with GPS, Bluetooth, wifi and battery all nicely boxed up and good to go. With COTS BT heart rate, speed and cadence sensors its a software problem.

Comment: Can't answer regarding available source code but as others have said, for the Pi, you'd want a non-Microsoft language as the Pi is Linux based. You may get more success posting this on the Pi forum or Stack Overflow :) I'd be interested in anything you find though.

Answer (score 3):

Lighting control isn't exactly a good idea since you have 2 lights (front and rear) on a bicycle typically.

Most cycling sensors (cadence, speed, heartrate, etc.) either speak [ANT+](http://www.thisisant.com/) or [Bluetooth](http://www.bluetooth.com/Pages/Bluetooth-Home.aspx) these days, so if you want to read sensors, you just need to know how to speak ANT+ or Bluetooth in your chosen language. You can also add a GPS module and other things as well.

People have accessed USB ANT+ sticks in [Python](http://blog.howrandom.net/blog/2012/10/01/monitoring-a-talk-from-pyconuk-2012/) and Bluetooth has a [cycling profile](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/CSCP.aspx) and many people have used Bluetooth with the Raspberry Pi.

Note that many phones have both ANT+ and bluetooth, and have their own built in batteries (and are probably faster than a Raspberry pi) and mobile internet, so if you want to read sensors, they may be better than the raspberry pi. That being said, either of these options will likely be far more battery draining than a cycling computer which provides the same functionality, so I'm guessing this is a project just for fun.

Comment: I saw someone do this as a specialty setup and basically project the speed and other info as a "HUD style" display on the ground in front of the bike with a HD projector (I think).  It was a very cool project, but not something that I considered necessarily useful for most people.